# RhinoMocks mock method without return

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am new to mocking. I need to mock method (it doesn't have return value). I cannot find any examples of how to mock a method. I need to mock `ITempDa.Import` method.

```
 var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ITempDA>();
 stub.Stub(x => x.Import(param1)). ???


 public void MockedImport() {
    // some processing here
 }
```

`ITempDa.Import` should be mocked and instead some internal method "`MockedImport`" should be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JamesLucas said you don't need to use `Return()` method(you should use this method only when your method is not `void`).

In this case you should use the `Do()` method:

```
var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ITempDA>();
stub.Stub(x => x.Import(Arg<object>.Is.Anything))
                .Do(new Action<object>(o => MockedImport()));
```

or if `MockedImport` ths same arguments as `Import`:

```
stub.Stub(x => x.Import(Arg<object>.Is.Anything))
                .Do(new Action<object>(MockedImport);
```

You should use `WhenCalled` method when the method under test called your fake and you want to intercept the execution(execute something + change return value/change arguments/do additional steps and etc...). Another reason to use `Do` instead of `WhenCalled` is, your code become more readable.

Usually I do not recommend to use `IgnoreArguments` method. The reason is quite simple, you test the method behaviour. When something violate the method behaviour then the test should fail. `IgnoreArguments` easily hide things. However, if the calling parameters aren't important do:

```
stub.Stub(x => x.Import(null))
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .Do(new Action<object>(o => MockedImport()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you don't need a Return() call as the method is void returning. If you want to intercept the call and perform some logic on the mocked operation then use WhenCalled. In this scenario it's also worht just ignoring the arguments in the Stub and handling everything in the WhenCalled expression. e.g.

```
 var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ITempDA>();
 stub.Stub(x => x.Import(null))
     .IgnoreArguments()
     .WhenCalled(invocation =>
     {
         var arg = invocation.Arguments[0] as ...;
         // etc
     });
```