# C# Mock method return value evaluate at the actual execution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'm using `Nunit` testing with `Rhino-Mocks` for my code unit testing.
My code is like below;

```
_mockHandler.Expect(m => m.DoSomething(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
            .Return(myList["XXX"]);
```

Content of the `myList` is updating from a thread running. Once the above line executing value of `myList["XXX"]` is empty. But at the time of this method invoke from the code `myList["XXX"]` is having a value.

Is there any way to configure, refer to the actual value when calling the method?

Answer (score 3):

The way to return value in runtime instead of record-time is to use `WhenCalled` or `Do` methods.

In your case it seems that `Do` is the right solution:(If you wants to know when to use `Do` or `WhenCalled` read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845222/rhinomocks-mock-method-without-return/30855341#30855341))

```
_mockHandler.Expect(m => m.DoSomething(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
                                       Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
            .Do(new Func<string,string,string>((s, s1) => myList["XXX"]));
```

In the above example `(s, s1) => myList["XXX"])` will execute when you call `DoSomething` and the value in `myList["XXX"]` will return.

Comment: Agree that `Do()` is the correct way to do this. I didn't think the final `Return()` was needed, though.